# What's the name of all the square brackets?

Tags: c++, arrays

In C++, we have square brackets in different places and I think it's sometimes important to distinguish them when talking to other developers. While I can call all of them "square brackets", I think they have better names, depending on what they do.

I am thinking of

1. array declaration, like `int arr[1024];`
2. array assignment, like `arr[13] = 17;`
3. array access, like `int x = arr[13];`
4. map (and other container) access, like `int y = map["key"];`
5. captures in lambdas, like `auto lambda = [&](){return 23 + arr[13];};`
6. the ones in `delete[]`
7. those of attributes like `[[deprecated("for reasons")]]`
8. the separation of a pair into its parts like `auto [x, y] = std::make_pair(1, 2);`

IMHO, the array assignment and array access brackets are called subscript operator. What about all the others? Do they have good names?

Comment: It is `operator[]`.

Comment: @JasonLiam Yes, many of them (2, 3 and 4) are implemented as `operator[]`, but they might still have different names.

Comment: For lambdas you already know the name: It's a *capture* clause. For some of the others some digging on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp should help you.

Comment: `operator[]` is also a name, isn't it? I mean generically we can call it `operator[]`.

Comment: Personally, I have never in the past thirty years felt a need for terminology to distinguish between them. Do you have an example of when you feel it would be important to do it?

Comment: @molbdnilo My colleague called the array declaration brackets (1.) "subscript operator" and I felt that this is the wrong term, because it doesn't subscript the array, if defines the size.

Comment: Sounds like the motivation for terminology is essentially to finish the sentence "It's not a subscript operator, it's \_\_\_" as a response to their colleague

Comment: 2 - 4 are all conceptually the same imho - they all access an "index," in a sense, of a memory structure.

Comment: `operator[]` is the most generic term that can/should be used IMO(when talking generically ofcourse).

Comment: brackets `[]`, parens `()`, braces `{}`. That's pretty universal I thought.

Comment: @john: that's correct. And we have angle brackets `<>` which are also called "brackets". In this question am only talking about different versions of the square brackets `[]`. At this moment, I don't care about all other sorts of symbols.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(2), (3), (4) — `arr[13]` — It's an operator. So, "subscript operator" or "square brackets operator"? To further point out the lhs type, "{map,vector,array} subscript operator"?

(1) — `int arr[1024];` — The grammar doesn't seem to have a name specifically for the brackets. The whole `arr[1024]` is an "(array) declarator".

> My colleague called the array declaration brackets (1.) "subscript operator" and I felt that this is the wrong term

I would point out that it's not an operator, without suggesting an other term. Just call them brackets.

(5) — `[...](){}` — This is commonly called a "lambda capture list". The grammar calls it a "lambda-introducer", but the term feels rather obscure.

(6) — `delete[]` — The whole thing is an [array delete (expression)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#1). The brackets themselves don't have a separate name.

(7) — `[[nodiscard]]` — The whole thing is an "attribute" (the grammar calls it an "attribute-specifier", or "...-seq" for a list of attributes). The double brackets themselves don't seem to have a separate name.

(8) — `auto [x, y]` — The whole thing is a "structured binding (declaration)", or a "decomposition declaration" (I've only seen the latter in Clang error messages, not in the standard). The brackets themselves don't have a separate name here. The thing enclosed in brackets is called an *identifier-list* in the grammar.

Answer (score 5):

1. is a *new declarator* as per [expr.new] (N4713, chapter 8.5.2.4, paragraph 5) and *new expression* [new.delete.array] (N4713, chapter 21.6.2.2) (when used with the `new` keyword).
2. Array assignment seems to be called *subscript operator* as per C++20 draft [expr.sub] (N4713, chapter 8.5.1.1).
3. same as 2.
4. probably same as 2., I didn't find a better reference yet
5. is a *labmda introducer* as per [expr.prim.lambda] (N4713, chapter 8.4.5)
6. `delete` is the *delete expression operator* as per C++20 draft [expr.delete] (N4713, chapter 8.5.2.5). The array version of it is just an alternative.
7. is an *attribute specifier* as per [dcl.attr.grammar] (N4713, chapter 10.6.1)
8. is a *structured binding declaration* as per [dcl.struct.bind] (N4713, chapter 11.5)

Source: [C++20 Draft N4713](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf)

Comment: 1 isn't a *new expression*, it lacks `new`

Comment: @Caleth: agreed. A `new` would allocate on the free store while in the question it's allocated on the stack. Any suggestion what I could look for in the Standard document?

Comment: Not every part of syntax has a name. It's *part* of the type, in a declarator.