# What's the name of all the angle brackets?

Tags: c++, c++20

In C++ we have angle brackets in different places and I think it's sometimes important to distinguish them when talking to other developers, e.g. during mob programming when navigating someone (e.g. "go to the arrow operator in line 36" or "now write the spaceship operator"). While I can of course call them "angle brackets", I think they have better names, depending on what they do.

I am thinking of

1. comparison, like `bool smaller = a < b;`
2. bit shift, like `auto x = 1 << 8;`
3. console output, like `std::cout << "Hello";`
4. console input, like `int age; std::cin >> age;`
5. types, like `std::vector<int> v;`
6. templates, like `template<typename T> T t() { return 0;}`
7. member templates, if that is any different to 6.
8. lambda parameters, like `[]<int>(){ return 5;}`
9. as part of pointers, like `a->b();`
10. similarly, but with an additional asterisk, like `x->*member();`
11. the new comparison, like `int compare = a <=> b;`
12. the new return types, like `auto main() -> int{}`
13. maybe even includes, like `#include <iomanip>;`, although these are preprocessor and not C++
14. for completeness sake, the funny stuff like `<:` and `:>`  or  `??<` and `??>`

Comment: Related: [What's the name of all the square brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73698496/whats-the-name-of-all-the-square-brackets)

Comment: I don't understand the question. do you mean how to read code? I can't come up with an example why you'd ever say "angle brackets" when read code.

Comment: Here you go just search for `>` or `<` (or anything else) [Punctuation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/punctuators)

Comment: @RichardCritten: that's an awesome link. Thank you. It'll make my future research much easier.

Comment: @ThomasWeller well, I don't speak code word by word, so I don't understand the point.

Comment: that's not my downvote, btw.

Comment: @appleapple: at my total reputation, I don't care about downvotes any more ;-) I'm just trying to document things I research for my team anyway and share it publically.

Comment: @ThomasWeller just in case you care about it.

Comment: Actually, the `<>` are used by the preprocessor which is part of the C++ language.  The `<>` files are searched in the system areas before using any Developer search paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In many cases, the angle brackets do not have a name themselves, because they are part of another construct.

1. is called *relational operator* [source: C++ 20 standard, chapter 7.6.9, [expr.rel], page 140], also *comparison operator* or just  *less-than operator* and *greater-than operator*
2. is called *shift operator* [source: C++ 20 standard, chapter 7.6.7, [expr.shift], page 139]
3. is called *insertion operator* [source: C++ 20 standard, chapter 29.7.5.6, [ostream.rvalue], page 1422], technically it's implemented as `operator<<`, just like the shift operator, but of course we don't call it shift operator, because we don't shift a stream.
4. is called *extraction operator* [source: C++ 20 standard, chapter 29.7.4.6, [istream.rvalue], page 1413]

I've also heard the term *chevron operator* as the superordinate term for both, *insertion operator* and *extraction operator*.

5. the whole thing (angle brackets plus type(s)) is called a *template argument list* [sources: C++ 20 standard, chapter 13.3, [temp.names], page 366, and chapter 13.4.1 (4), [temp.arg], page 369].
6. the whole thing is a *template parameter list* [source: C++ 20 standard, chapter 13.1, [temp.pre], page 360]
7. like 6
8. this is also called a *template parameter list* [source: C++ 20 standard,  chapter 7.5.5.1 (5), [expr.prim.lambda.general], page 103]

Regarding the last four: it's a parameter list in the declaration and an argument list when it's used.

9. is an *arrow* or *-> operator* (probably pronounced *arrow operator*) [source: C++ 20 standard, chapter 7.6.1.5, [expr.ref], page 110].
10. is a *pointer to member operator* [source: C++ 20 standard, chapter 7.6.4, [expr.mptr.oper], page 137].
11. is called the *three way comparison operator*  [source: C++ 20 standard, chapter 7.6.8, [expr.spaceship], page 140] or simply the *spaceship operator*.
12. is called a *trailing return type* [source: C++ 20 standard, chapter 9.3.1, [dcl.decl.general], page 183]. For concepts, there's a similar thing called *return type requirement* [source: C++ 20 standard, chapter 7.5.7.4, [expr.prim.req.compound], page 115]
13. is a *header name* [source: C++ 20 standard, chapter 5.8, [lex.header], page 16] and similar in [source: C++ 20 standard, chapter 15.2, [cpp.cond], page 462]
14. the whole thing is a *digraph* [source: C++ 20 standard, chapter 5.5, [lex.digraph], page 15] or *trigraph* (until C++14) [source: C++ 20 standard, chapter C.2.2, [diff.cpp14.lex], page 1662]

Comment: there's also the "goes to" operator :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c

Comment: @bolov: that one is funny.